# Spark on Yarn job not being accepted by Yarn: YarnScheduler:66 - Initial job has not accepted any resources

Tags: apache-spark, scheduled-tasks, hadoop-yarn

I am getting

> YarnScheduler:66 - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources`

when I executing execute any command in spark-shell (master - yarn), for example a simple one: `sc.parallelize(1 to 10).count()`. Yarn log does not help much. Here is the yarn log when I started `spark-shell --master yarn --num-executors 1`

```
2019-08-06 01:55:12 INFO  RMProxy:98 - Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8030
2019-08-06 01:55:12 INFO  YarnRMClient:54 - Registering the ApplicationMaster
2019-08-06 01:55:12 INFO  YarnAllocator:54 - Will request 1 executor container(s), each with 1 core(s) and 884 MB memory (including 384 MB of overhead)
2019-08-06 01:55:12 INFO  YarnAllocator:54 - Submitted 1 unlocalized container requests.
```

Here is the configuration from yarn-site.xml:

```
<property> 
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
  <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value> 
</property>

<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value> 
</property>

<property> 
  <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
  <value>2048</value> 
</property>

<property> 
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
  <value>2048</value> 
</property>

<property> 
  <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
  <value>true</value> 
</property>

<property> 
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
  <value>/tmp/logs</value> 
</property>
```

Here is configuration from spark-defaults.conf:

```
spark.master                     spark://192.168.56.109:7077
spark.eventLog.enabled           false
#spark.driver.memory              3g
spark.executor.memory            512m
spark.yarn.am.memory             1g
```

There is no issue when I am running it in Spark standalone cluster mode however. I have tried all options for past 1 week to resolve this problem but met with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your machine have enough resources/memory? The error quite self-descriptive isn't it?

Standalone mode and yarn mode is totally different.

Yarn itself is a java program, so it will consume memory as well and probably this caused your machine do not have enough memory to be allocated for the spark job?

Comment: I am running Redhat Linux 7 on Oracle Virtual Box with 9 GB memory and 2 cores. After I started the cluster, yarn and spark application I still have 2425 MB free memory (+ 287 MB buffer/cache and 61 MB shared) reported by free -m. Yarn has 2048 Memory, 1 VCores.